# How to get product by name attribute

Tags: magento2

I want get product by `sku, name, price.`I do not know how to get it. Please help me. i get it by `sku` is success but name or price isn't success.

Answer (score 1):

you can get product by name or price by using this code

```
namespace Abdus\Test\Helper;



class HelperData extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_productsFactory;

    public function __construct(

        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productFactory

    )
    {

        $this->_productsFactory = $productFactory;

    }

    public function getProductCollection($productId)
    {
          $price = 500;
          $name = 'little shirt';

        $productCollection = $this->_productsFactory->create()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('price', $price)
                        ->addFieldToFilter('name', $name)
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        return $productCollection;
    }
```

}